# How can I handle flagged posts?

Tags: support, specific-question, flagging

I have started getting yellow notifications of flagged posts. For example, [this one](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/28845/simplepie-the-data-could-not-be-converted-to-utf-8).

When I look at the original post I see that it has been closed.  On the 'flagged' page the only option is a button marked "flag or disagree" and below it a comment that says:

> Please explain the nature of this closed question via a comment

When I click the button I get a page that offers me the chance to flag the post - but it appears already to have been flagged (else why is it in a 'flagged' page).

I'm confused how I should respond.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand it correctly, when a question is closed but the close is not explained with a comment, it is automatically flagged for moderator attention with the reason you quoted.

So, look at the question and the close reason. If you think a comment would be useful, add it; if not, don't.

Since there is no way to say “I already handled this flag”, I *think* what you should do after that is to mark the flag as invalid (either because it's not valid anymore or because it wasn't valid in the first place, because you think a comment isn't needed).

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'll have to see if I get on better next time :-)